# xamarin.ios - adding views to tableitem programmatically

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I'm building an interface in codes from scratch (there's nothing in XIB file). I'm adding a tableitem that consists of some cells and those cells contains one or more views (UIButton, UITextField, etc.)

The problem is none of the items are clickable/editable! When I click TextFields or Buttons, nothing happens! No highlighting, no cursor changing nothing at all...

What I'm missing here?

Comment: Are you adding your views to the UITableViewCell or to its ContentView? You should to add them to the latter.

Comment: I'm adding them to ContentView

Answer (score 0):

Also constructed the cells programmatically. I am adding controls directly to the UITableViewCell.

One possible issue: some of your views (may be ContentView or the UITableViewCell) hides the controls from manipulation. You should set that [UIView].userInteractionEnabled to false. You can also try to implement touch listeners to your views to recognize which one hides your controls.